# Reuse a route in a different route

Tags: ember.js

I want to reuse a route inside a different route.
Example:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('routeA', function() {
        this.resource('routeAA');
    });
    this.resource('routeB', function() {
        this.resource('routeA', function() {
            this.resource('routeAA');
        });
    });
});
```

This is not working because I think the first resource routeA gets overridden in routeB.

Is my speculation correct? 
Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: I just found this: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1793. Option 2 sounds reasonable, but I got a ton of links in my template for which I have to implement a ton of conditionals. Should I go with this or does somebody know a better solution?